# subprocess open ('source venv/bin/activate'),no such file?

Tags: python, subprocess, virtualenv

I want get into virtual environment in python files.But it raise no such files.

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.Popen(['source', '/Users/XX/Desktop/mio/worker/venv/bin/activate'])
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/Ru/Desktop/mio/worker/run.py", line 3, in 
>       subprocess.Popen(['source', '/Users/Ru/Desktop/mio/worker/venv/bin/activate'])
>
> File"/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)
>
> File"/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception
>
> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code doesn't work because you are separating the 'source' command from the virtualenv path argument, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

> "Note in particular that options (such as -input) and arguments (such
>   as eggs.txt) that are separated by whitespace in the shell go in
>   separate list elements, **while arguments that need quoting or
>   backslash escaping when used in the shell (such as filenames
>   containing spaces or the echo command shown above) are single list
>   elements.**"

You should try one of two things:
First, write the source and the virtualenv file path as a single string argument:

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.Popen(['source '/Users/XX/Desktop/mio/worker/venv/bin/activate'])
```

I'm working on OSX and that doesn't seem to work, but it might be due to the shell you are using. To ensure this will work, you can use the shell=True flag:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['source '/Users/XX/Desktop/mio/worker/venv/bin/activate'],shell=True)
```

This will use /bin/sh shell by default. Again, you can read more in the documentation.

Tom.

Comment: It seems that it works,but i still can't import my moudle in venv.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/XX/Desktop/mio/worker/run.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pika`

Comment: Please paste some more of your code so I can understand its flow...

BTW I can see that you're trying to import a file named pika... if you are building some king of Pokemon(TM) game/integration with Pokemon go then please get a life and build something else (just kidding, I just can't relate to that game :P).

Comment: `import subprocess`

`subprocess.Popen(['source /Users/Ru/Desktop/mio/worker/venv/bin/activate'],shell=True)`

Comment: and then
`import pika`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ru/Desktop/mio/worker/run.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pika
ImportError: No module named pika
/bin/bash: shell_session_update: command not found
[Finished in 0.9s with exit code 1]`

Comment: Pika is a pure-Python implementation of the AMQP 0-9-1 protocol that tries to stay fairly independent of the underlying network support library. :)

Comment: Please see my new answer, hope I got it right this time :)

Answer (score 1):

There is another simpler way to do what you want.
If you want a python script to use a virtualenv you can always use the python interpreter from the virualenv itself.

/Users/Ru/Desktop/mio/worker/venv/bin/python my_python_file.py

This will run the my_python_file.py with the properties/libraries of the virtualenv.

If you want to run that file inside a subprocess you can do something similar to the method I described above:

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.Popen(['/Users/Ru/Desktop/mio/worker/venv/bin/python my_python_file.py])
```

and have my_python_file.py import pika and do other actions you wish to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run shell builtins like `source` (or `cd`, etc) without a shell.

Technically, you could pass a string with `shell=True`, but that would still be pointless, because the changes made to the environment of that subprocess are irretrievably lost immediately when that subprocess exits. It cannot affect the environment of your Python script, which is clearly what you want to achieve.

The simple solution is to activate the virtual environment before launching your Python script.